# Java - "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I know this has been asked many times, and I've looked for a few hours now but have come up with no solution.

> "Error: Could not find or load main class bradley.discord.bot.DiscordBot"

The bot starts up in IntelliJ using 'Run' but `java -jar DiscordBot.jar` produces the above error. I've already setup the manifest, so I don't think that's the problem.

[image: IntelliJ Class View]

Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: json-simple-1.1.jar nv-websocket-client-2.0.jar unirest-ja
 va-1.4.9.jar servlet-api-2.5.jar commons-io-2.5.jar httpcore-4.4.4.ja
 r base64-2.3.9.jar antlr-3.2.jar commons-logging-1.2.jar JDA-3.0.0_18
 9.jar google-oauth-client-1.22.0.jar commons-codec-1.2.jar jline-0.9.
 94.jar httpasyncclient-4.1.1.jar cassandra-thrift-0.8.1.jar jackson-d
 atabind-2.8.5.jar google-http-client-1.22.0.jar jackson-core-asl-1.4.
 0.jar guava-r08.jar jetty-util-6.1.22.jar jsoup-1.10.1.jar libthrift-
 0.6.1.jar jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar google-http-client-jackson2-1
 .22.0.jar jamm-0.2.2.jar commons-lang3-3.5.jar trove4j-3.0.3.jar juni
 t-4.4.jar cassandra-all-0.8.1.jar slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar antlr-2.7.7
 .jar httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar commons-collections-3.2.1.jar jetty-6.1.2
 2.jar google-api-services-youtube-v3-rev183-1.22.0.jar servlet-api-2.
 5-20081211.jar antlr-runtime-3.2.jar httpmime-4.5.2.jar commons-colle
 ctions4-4.1.jar commons-lang-2.6.jar avro-1.4.0-cassandra-1.jar forms
 _rt-5.0.jar lavaplayer-1.2.36.jar jsr305-1.3.9.jar guava-jdk5-17.0.ja
 r lavaplayer-common-1.0.4.jar google-api-client-1.22.0.jar jna-4.4.0.
 jar concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.1.jar jackson-mapper-asl-1.4.0.jar
 json-20160810.jar stringtemplate-3.2.jar commons-cli-1.1.jar high-sca
 le-lib-1.1.2.jar jackson-core-2.8.5.jar httpclient-4.5.2.jar snakeyam
 l-1.6.jar slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar
Main-Class: bradley.discord.bot.DiscordBot
```

Comment: check your jar file has the compiled classes and in the exact package structure

Comment: @prajeeshkumar Yes, it does: http://prntscr.com/f7mt9v

Comment: It a maven project. right? How do u generating the executable jar file?

Comment: @Pete Yes it's maven, and I generate it by building the artifact, here's the settings: http://prntscr.com/f7muhx

Comment: Post the complete stack trace of the exception, always. And post the content of the current directory (as returned by `ls` or `dir`).

Comment: There isn't a stack trace, just "Error: Could not find or load main class bradley.discord.bot.DiscordBot".

Comment: And post the content of the current directory (as returned by ls or dir).

Comment: @JBNizet https://pastebin.com/SVfj9Rum

Comment: That's not what I asked you to do. All I can conclude from what you posted is that you're trying to execute DiscordBot.jar, but your jar file is named Bot.jar. I can also conclude that your jar file contains plenty of other jar files, that should not be there, but should be in the current directory, next to your jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try building the executable jar file with some maven plugins, for example below one used maven-assembly-plugin to build the executable jar.

```
<!-- Maven Assembly Plugin -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>bradley.discord.bot.DiscordBot</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Use the generated `*.jar-with-dependencies.jar` to run with `java -jar`

Comment: Can you post your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Try by removing `maven-jar-plugin` from pom and use the generated `*.jar-with-dependencies.jar` to run

Comment: Where can I find the generated jar?

Comment: It should be in the `target` directory, if the maven build result is success

Comment: After compiling **with** dependencies it still produces main not found.

Comment: What was the build result for `maven install`? was it success?

Comment: It still runs the ` maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar)`. And you shoul execute `java -jar Bot-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`.

Comment: IT WORKS, thanks, so IntelliJ was moving my jar-with-dependencies file to another location, after running it I had to install a few other apache dependencies due to ClassNotDef.. thanks for your help and patience @Pete